# Can you pass a boolean to a switch statement?

Tags: matlab, switch-statement, boolean, case

I've been looking all over for an answer to this question, but can't seem to find it. I know that boolean operators can't be used in a switch case because they return true or false rather than something that could match the input, i.e.

```
switch (...)
    case (a || b)
```

but is it valid to use one in the initial switch statement? The particular code I'm using is

```
switch num < -2 || num > 4
    case 1
         ...
    otherwise
         ...
end

%I'm new and don't know if all languages work like this, but I'm using MATLAB where 1 == true
```

My professor insists that this is an incorrect use of switch, and while I'm inclined to trust her, my script worked exactly as intended. This should be a sound method based on my understanding of how switch works, but she won't explain why/clarify what she means. Am I missing something?

Comment: your professor is right: switch use case is when you have to choose between a certain amount of values. In this case you have only two possibilities - true or false - so a normal if/else makes much more sense.

Comment: The `switch` _works_, but it's more readable and simpler to use `if` when you have two possibilities. Using `switch` here would be like using `inv` (matrix inversion) to compute the inverse of a number: `inv(5)` works, but you would nomally use `1/5`

Comment: the `switch` statement just sees the result of your `num < -2 || num > 4` calculation. Therefore, it is either `true` or `false` (which is interpreted as `1` or `0` afterwards topping the confusion off^^). So Luis is right, it perfectly works but is bad practice... in particular if you could have just use `if`-`else` if you have a boolean case;) (if you have more cases, think of `if`-`elseif`-`else`)